# New 18.04.2 installation problems

Tags: 18.04, usb-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu - just installed a week ago and not familiar with terminology.  My desktop has no top menu.  I can't see the 3x3 dots Application icon shown in U-Tube guidance videos. When selecting Software in the menu I get SSL handshake error.  I can't load any software e.g.can't link my HP printer.  Guidance appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that all updates are installed? Please open terminal and then run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`. Then reboot and retry to run Software.

Comment: Thanks NOrbert.  I ran update and upgrade.  Version is now 18.04.6 and I can now access the software options.  Now time to learn this new system.

Comment: Just for FYI:  18.04.3 release - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/ & latest 18.04.6 release - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/   Your stating 18.04.2 implies you haven't upgraded past 18.04.3 or 2019-August-08 (*for ISO release date; installed systems actually upgraded to that a couple of weeks before that ISO release date, I'm providing ISO release dates as that's verifiable*).   I would jump to terminal & `sudo apt update` to verify no warnings/errors and detail is as it should be.. then `sudo apt full-upgrade` - again checking

Answer (score 4):

Right away it is apparent that you did something wrong because the current point release for Ubuntu 18.04 is 18.04.6, not 18.04.2.

18.04.2 came out in February 2019, almost three years ago.  This is not appropriate for having installed Ubuntu a week ago.

You should download and [create bootable installation media](https://ubuntu.com/search?q=Create+bootable+usb) based on an [up-to-date release](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) and then [reinstall Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Don't forget to verify the integrity of your download and flashed media to ensure that the download and the flash are uncorrupted.  If your installation media is corrupted, it greatly decreases the chance for a successful installation.

Comment: Thanks Nmath.  My daughter bought Xtra-PC for my birthday to try and bring life to my old desktop.  Version 18.04.6 is now installed.  Next job is to try and link my printer.  Lots to learn.  Thanks.

Comment: If the printer is not detected automatically, it may need a driver from the manufacturer. Check their support website for this model to look for a 64-bit driver for debian-based Linux and review their installation instructions. Generally a `.deb` file is provided which can be opened with your GUI package manager. If you need additional help with this problem you can open up a new question